# Cardinality of the set of all mathematical statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, cardinals

Let A = {x|x is a mathematical statement}.

What is the cardinality of A?

This was a question my friend asked me yesterday.

At first, I thought A is a countable set because one can count the number of statements. Namely, I can establish a bijection between A and set of natural numbers, by assigning a unique natural number to each statement.

However, my friend then asked "How about having a math statement such that x = y, while x and y are arbitrary element of real number set? Then, the total number of mathematical statement would be equal to the cardinality of the power set of real number set?"

After listening to his argument, I became completely puzzled. Can anyone verify whether one of us have a correct reasoning? Or both of us are wrong?

Comment: I would imagine we should more adequately define what a mathematical statement is before getting too much further.  Most definitions I see are merely "*a sentence that is either true or false but not both*" in which case that might lead us to try to define a sentence as well.  Must a sentence be finite in length and contain characters from a predefined finite collection of permissible characters and symbols?  If so I would argue for $A$ being countably infinite as it would effectively be a subset of the set of finite-length strings over our collection of characters.

Comment: I would further argue that although the statement $x=y$ where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary reals may be applicable to uncountably many different scenarios, it is itself just the one statement.  For perhaps a better example, $\forall x\in \Bbb Z^+~:~x>0$.  You could argue that this is *equivalent* to (*but different than since it used different characters*) $1>0\wedge 2>0\wedge 3>0\wedge 4>0\wedge \dots$ but should that also be considered a statement were it to be infinite in length with each inequality explicitly written out?

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the reply. What my friend meant could be this. Statement 1: 1=1, St2: 1=1.1, St3: 1=1.12... and continue making statements having 1 equal to all other real numbers. Then, can we yield uncountably many different statements?

Comment: regarding the first comment, he was talking about the standard definition of mathematical statement: a sentence that is either true or false but not both. And yes, he would like to limit the length of sentence to be finite, using finitely many characters and symbols.

Comment: @ David your reply to @JMoravitz sounds like your friend is saying we can list the real numbers, which is false.

Comment: @HiMatt yeah I know that's why I got puzzled. How could one list all the real numbers? Impossible.

Comment: @David That's neither here nor there. You can't list all the real numbers, sure... and yet when somebody asks how many of them there are, you answer without hesitation. If you consider "$r=1$" to be a "mathematical statement" for every real number $r$, then there are continuum-many such statements. The question is whether you should consider it as such. Such abstract sentences are frequently reasoned about in mathematical logic, but you can't write them down concretely. They certainly aren't sentences in the language in which we do mathematics... you can't write down an "arbitrary real number"

Comment: Despite there being uncountably infinitely many reals, we are only able to uniquely and precisely describe finitely many of them within a finite number of characters.  So, although there may be uncountably many "*potential statements*" if one could call them that asking if $1$ is equal to some other specific real number, I would argue that the vast majority of those cannot be written in a sentence and thus should not qualify as actually being statements themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There are countably many symbols used in stating a math statement.
Each math statement is a finite sequence of those symbols.
There are countably math statements of length n.
Add them all up for a countably many statements.

In practice there are finite many math statements.

Answer (score 0):

Given the "set" A = {x: x is a mathematical statement}, there is no possible way to quantify the size of the "set". In axiomatic set theory- it actually would be considered a proper class and not a set and therefore not possible to quantify. Let me break this down more below:

Like your friend mentioned above, the set R = $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x=x\}$ of all statements "x = x, where x is a real number" alone would have the cardinality $2^{\aleph_{0}}$, where $ \aleph_0$ is the cardinality of the integers (See Cantor).

How about $\mathcal{P}(R)$, the power set of R? It has a cardinality of $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. The union of R and $\mathcal{P}(R)$ would also have cardinality of $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

$ \aleph_0$, $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, etc. are known as cardinal numbers. Take $\mathcal{P}^i(R)))$, the ith iteration of taking power sets of R.  then we can define a set $A_i = \{x \in \mathcal{P}^i(R))): x=x\}$ of all statements "x=x, where x is an element of $\mathcal{P}^i(R)))$.

Now take the union of all such $A_i$ and call it U; U would be the collection of all mathematical statements x=x, where x is an element of some $\mathcal{P}^i$(R). Given the definition of A above, every statement in U would also be in A.

We see that each successive union of the elements of $A_i$ would have larger and larger sizes of infinite cardinalities and therefore when all of them are combined into U it cannot converge to any size. Since all statements in U would also be statements, it follows A cannot have a definitive size.